# Speeding up rnorm in for cycle

Tags: r, performance, montecarlo, random

I'm trying to write a function for estimate uncertainty budget based on Monte Carlo method. Here I'll report just the piece of code I need to speed up.

```
inout<-function(var1,svar1,var2,svar2){
          M<-10^6

          var1m<-matrix(nrow=length(var1),ncol=M)
          var2m<-matrix(nrow=length(var2),ncol=M)

          j<-1
          for (j in 1:length(var1)) {
            var1m[j,]<-var1[j]+rnorm(M,0,svar1[j])
            var2m[j,]<-var2[j]+rnorm(M,0,svar2[j])
          }
          var1a<-apply(var1m,1,mean)
          var2a<-apply(var2m,1,mean)
          return(list(a=round(var1a,digits=1),b=round(var2a,digits=1)))
        }

 fake1<-cbind(rnorm(200,10,1),rnorm(200,1,0.1),rnorm(200,15,2),rnorm(200,2,0.1))
 fake2<-cbind(rnorm(200,5,1),rnorm(200,2,0.1),rnorm(200,150,2),rnorm(200,4,0.1))
 inout(var1=fake[,1],svar1=fake[,2],var2=fake[,3],svar2=fake[,4])
```

For my purpose it's very important that each element `j` of `var1` it's associated with its `rnorm(M,0,svar1[j])` term.
Thank you.

AB

Comment: Just looking over your code, argument `svar2`is not used anywhere (should `svar2<-vector(length=length(var1))` end in `var2`?).  Also, the last argument in your last line (example use): you haven't defined `svar2[,4]` anywhere (R should complain, even if your function doesn't use it).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the same:

```
inout2<-function(var1,svar1,var2,svar2, M){
  var1m <- matrix(rnorm(M*length(var1), mean=0, sd=rep(svar1, each=M)), 
                  ncol=length(var1))
  var2m <- matrix(rnorm(M*length(var2), mean=0, sd=rep(svar2, each=M)), 
                  ncol=length(var2))

  var1a <- colMeans(var1m) + var1
  var2a <- colMeans(var2m) + var2

  return(list(a=round(var1a,digits=1),b=round(var2a,digits=1)))
}
```

Are you aware that (due to the rounding) the result will be quite often independent of `svar1` and `svar2` if `M` is sufficiently large?

Comment: Yes, this will happen just in this example, not with the real dataset and the real function. I tried your solution but the result it's not exactly the same (also with set.seed). I don't know why.

Comment: The result cannot be exactly the same because you alternate between creating random numbers for var1m and var2m whereas my code creates first all random numbers for var1m and then all random numbers for var2m. The random sequences must be different.